# How to push to an array without explicit declaration?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array of Rails app User objects (users) and I am gathering email entries from these objects in a new array. I am tired of doing:

```
emails = []
users.each {|user| emails << user.email}
```

Is there a way to declare and use an array in a single go in an enumerator block like that?

Comment: With my Rails-fu grown in power, I now know that the way to go about this is to use pluck. For example, `User.where(<some_condition>).pluck(:email)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`#collect`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-collect) method

```
users.collect {|user| user.email }
# in short
users.collect(&:email)
```

*collect* emails will be nice to read rather than *map* emails, so I will use `#collect`. But both the methods are synonym of each other.

Comment: `Array` surely has this method and acts the same way, but `users` might not be an `Array`. What it surely is, is `Enumerable`: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-collect

Comment: @D-side Thanks... No argument :)

Answer (score 1):

There is [`#each_with_object`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) method.

```
users.each_with_object( [] ) {|user, emails| emails << user.email}
```

Not really a good example, `collect` works much better here, since you need an array. However, if you ever happen to use a different container, not an array (maybe some custom class), this might be handy.

And I also have to note that it looks much like `ActiveRecord` usage, since it's about Rails. So you might find [`#pluck`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pluck) useful:

I can't provide an equal piece of code here, because I have no idea what do you have in `users`. But here's a similar snippet:

```
User.all.pluck(:email)
```